# Blender rock UV seams visible all the time

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

So I've been trying to get the hang of making some rocks inside Blender. I've tried a couple different ways of sculpting the rock with quads and triangles using the multires mod.

The problem I'm having is that on all the rocks is that when they are unwrapped and I've baked the high to the low the seams from the unwrap are still visible. This is not just a Blender problem, I've taken the rocks into Unreal Engine 4 as well (not these rocks specifically) and the UV seams are still visible and affect the textures as well.

The reason I'm confused is that I've used this method before, except I used XNormal, the reason I'm not using it for these rocks at the moment is that exporting out from Blender is a bit taxing on my system. Another thing is that when I render the rocks in Blender I can actually see the polygons of the low poly, like it was not smooth shaded (which it is), this doesn't affect anything in UE4 so it's fine but If anyone has a fix to it please tell me. I was also using a cage for the baking.

Images of the rock, normal map and UV unwrap below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1][image][image]

Comment: First, change *Color* to *Non-Color Data* in the options of the image texture node for the normal map. Then, did you set shading to Smooth before baking normal map or after?

Comment: I had the object smooth shaded before I baked

Comment: I just tried the non-colour out on the map and it appears to have fixed it completely. Thank you so much, you're awesome.

Comment: Also would you happen to know a way to do this kind of thing in ue4? I was hoping to used this method in there for game assets

Comment: Search through their manual; the Unreal Engine questions belong to their forum, ask it there and you will have better chances to get asnwer.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway, just thought it might be quicker since I already had you here that you might be able to answer it. Thanks again.